# How to transfer an answer to another jframe?

Tags: java, swing, netbeans

For example I have two jframes. In the first frame is calculator and in another only text field, where answer will be placed. Would it be possible after clicking calculate button in first jframe to get answer in the second jframe text field?

Thanks.

Comment: [Similar questions link](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=site:stackoverflow.com+java+transfer+information+between+JFrames). Also see [The Use of Multiple JFrames: Good or Bad Practice?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9554636/the-use-of-multiple-jframes-good-or-bad-practice)

Comment: In the future, please search on your problem before asking, because as you can see from the links above, this is a common question on this and on many other sites. If you do search, then show the fruits of your efforts (and your code) with your question. No sense re-asking something that's been asked many times previously.